# Is it possible to select all vertices of all meshes so I can recalculate normals on everything at once?

Tags: mesh, layers

I have imported an OBJ file and removed duplicate vertices off of each layer.  Is there a way to select all vertices of all meshes so I can recalculate normals on everything at once?  or do I have to go through each layer again to do this?